# Extract feature of custom tab form Porto theme: Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Basically I want to add a custom tab feature which already exists in Porto theme to my custom module in Magento 2.
[image: i want to add tabs like this]

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of the configuration?

Comment: How to share the screenshot here?

Comment: Edit your question and insert the screenshot.

Comment: Do you want this feature in your custom extension configuration?

Comment: i want to make extension for this feature

Comment: any idea?@Sumit